# Label production using layout manager or null

Tags: java

I have to create a label to be used for deliveries. At the moment because it is being pushed as needing a quick solution i am creating a JFrame putting all the components on then saving the contents as an image and disposing the frame so it flashes up for an instant and then vanishes, ready to print out. If I know the Label will always be X by Y would it be better to set the layout manager as null and place the components in the positions I need them or would it be better to use a layout manager?

I am currently using a flow layout manager and had to set the preffered size of the sender panel to be a bit larger so that it moved down to the next section (under the barcode). Is there a particular LayoutManager that would be good for this?

---

[image: Target Layout]

**^^^ The above is the target Layout ^^^**

---

**vvv Below is what I have currently achieved vvv**

[image: current Layout]

---

**^^^ Currently achived Layout ^^^**

Also is there an easy way to draw lines like in the first picture?

Comment: How about [box layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html)? You can apile the components in Y axis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lot of people use JasperReports for this kind of work. It is easy to produce barcodes.

The library can be downloaded here

http://sourceforge.net/projects/jasperreports/?source=directory

The report is created using [iReports](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ireport/?source=directory)

You view your label as a report into which you inject your data.

May be a bit of leap wrt learning curve but when you get it working it is a very powerful tool.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you should be able to draw the frame to the Graphics of a BufferedImage without actually showing it on screen. Simply packing it to make id displayable should be enough.

That said, I believe you would be most flexible (in terms of font, separating lines, perhaps overlaps, text wrapping or truncation, and so on) by not generating UI components at all, but instead directly creating the whole image on the Graphics device. Obviously without a layout manager.